# C++ how is it technically possible to move a function return value without a copy?

Tags: c++, move

When a function returns a value, this is put on the stack (the function stack frames are deleted, but the return value remains there until the caller gets it).

If the return value is on the stack how can the move get that value without copying it in the variable memory location?

For example in this code:

```
A a = getA();
```

Comment: *When a function returns a value, this is put on the stack.* This assumption is false.

Comment: Good. Is it on the heap? If it is, than it could just copy the pointer.

Comment: Are you talking about C++ move semantics, or some other definition of "move?"

Comment: @Kami: It's (typically) put into the caller's stack frame.

Comment: The address of `a` is typically passed to `getA` and then `getA` constructs the object directly into that address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many implementations of C++, a function returning a "complex" data type is passed a hidden parameter that is a pointer to the space where the returned instance is to reside. Essentially, the compiler turns `Foo r = fun();` into

```
char alignas(Foo) r[sizeof Foo]; // Foo-sized buffer, unitialized!
fun(&r);
```

As you can see, `Foo` is allocated on the stack in the caller's frame. Now, within the implementation of `fun` there could be a copy. The construction

```
Foo fun() {
  Foo rv;
  ...
  return rv;
}
```

is generally implemented as

```
void fun(Foo * $ret) {
  Foo rv;
  ..
  new ($ret) Foo(rv); // copy construction
}
```

When the return value optimizations are applied, this gets changed to

```
void fun(Foo * $ret) {
  Foo & rv = *(new ($ret) Foo);
  ...
  return;
}
```

Now there's no copying involved. That's a mile-high overview of how an implementation might do it.

Comment: Do you know of any good books that explain how languages are implemented? (apart from the famous dragon book which I already know).

Comment: @Kami Such details are called ABIs - Application Binary Interfaces. Each platform has one or more of those. The ABI describes how data is arranged in memory, how parameters are passed, how names are mangled, etc. An ABI describes at a more concrete level what I wrote above. Again, a compiler does those things at a much lower level, it isn't actually generating ASTs for the code I've shown. It could, but good luck with debug info generation etc.

Comment: @Kami Also note that for certain things, there's really only one or two practical ways of doing it. What I described above is a construct that can be arrived at without having looked at any compiler book or source code. If you think about it long enough, you'll see that the above is one of the few sensible ways of doing it - it is also a rather abstract description. An implementation might, for example, pass the hidden parameters in a way that differs from regular parameters - so you couldn't "write" any void-returning C++ function that was binary compatible with a `Foo`-returning one.

Answer (score 3):

The storage (Heap, stack, registers, etc) used to store the temporary used to return values from a function is implementation defined. You could see it as:

```
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| target (caller stack frame) | temporary (unspecified) | return statement (function stack frame) | 
+-----------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

The value is passed from the right to the left. Also note that the standard specifies that any compiler could elide the temporary and the assigments/copies/moves and directly initialize the target.

Writting a class such as:

```
class trace
{
public:
    trace()
    { 
        std::cout << "Init" << std::endl;
    }

    ~trace()
    { 
        std::cout << "Destroy" << std::endl;
    }

    trace( const trace& )
    { 
        std::cout << "Copy init" << std::endl;
    }

    trace( trace&& )
    { 
        std::cout << "Move init" << std::endl;
   }

    trace& operator=( const trace& )
    { 
        std::cout << "Copy assign" << std::endl;
    }

    trace& operator=( trace&& )
    { 
        std::cout << "Move assign" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And trying it with different compiler optimizations enabled is very ilustrative.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that A is an aggregate or primitive. If this is true then yes move and copy semantics are equivalent. If however A is a complex type like vector then it will contain pointers to resources. When moving  the object the pointers are copied without copying the value they point to.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "move", I assuming you're referring to C++11 [move constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) and the `std::move` function.

Moving an object doesn't actually move the entire object.  It constructs a new one using its move constructor, which is allowed to take ownership of resources held by the original object instead of copying them.  For example, if you write:

```
std::vector<int> foo = function_that_returns_a_vector();
```

the compiler may implement this by calling `foo`'s move constructor and passing it the temporary vector returned by the function.  The move constructor will take ownership of the temporary vector's internal pointer to its heap-allocated contents, leaving the temporary vector empty.  Prior to C++11 and move support, `foo`'s *copy* constructor would've been called, which would've allocated new space on the heap to copy the returned vector's contents even though that returned vector is about to be destroyed and won't need its own copy any longer.

Note that the compiler won't necessarily implement that line by constructing `foo` from a returned temporary at all, though.  Depending on the compiler's platform-specific calling convention, the address of the (uninitialized) `foo` variable may be passed into the function in such a way that the function's return value is constructed directly into `foo`, avoiding the need for a copy after the function returns.  This is called [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to modify your method like this:

```
void getA(A& out);

A a;
getA(a);
```

However, your compiler does it's best to avoid such superfluity: [Copy Elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)